# ZF2 - Attaching a listener AFTER the render has been done

Tags: zend-framework2

I'm working with a massive application that doesn't have a defined way to handle layouts. So there are a lot of them. I'm trying to find a way to attach some HTML code to all of the views in the system, without having to hunt down every layout file and paste it.

My first thought was to attach a listener to the `MvcEvent::EVENT_RENDER` event but it seems it executes previous to the render being done, so I can't append a HTML string to it.  Of course I could pass a subview or similar but that'd mean I still have to hunt every layout file and add the line to render that child.

Is there a way I can attach a listener to an event fired AFTER the render?

Comment: Can you post the code for attaching your event listener. Remember you can listen for "pre" and "post" events by changing the priority. You could try setting priority to -9999 for your event listener

Comment: Does MvcEvent::EVENT_FINISH could resolve your problem ?

Comment: you have to develop own renderer instead of using zend default phprenderer